# Jetstream Installation Failed: could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream

I'm getting this error while installing **Laravel Jetstream**:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/jetstream[v2.3.0, ..., 2.x-dev] require league/commonmark ^1.3 -> found league/commonmark[1.3.0, ..., 1.6.x-dev] but the package is fixed to 2.0.0 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/jetstream ^2.3 -> satisfiable by laravel/jetstream[v2.3.0, ..., 2.x-dev].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

it's a fresh installed **Laravel Framework 8.51.0**

Answer (score 1):

This command:

```
composer require laravel/jetstream
```

also generated the same errors as you for me, but this other command works fine:

```
composer require laravel/jetstream:*
```

Answer (score 0):

I try these answers but it does not work for me, so I try this one.

first, should install Jetstream in a new Laravel application (read this doc from Jetstream laravel :https://jetstream.laravel.com/2.x/installation.html).
first step:

1. install new laravel project version 8
2. `composer require laravel/jetstream:*`
   and it's done
   continue the installation for the jetstream

Answer (score 0):

The Laravel 8 docs not clear. You can fix it by following commands:

```
php artisan jetstream:install livewire

npm install && npm run dev
```

**Reference:**

- https://github.com/laravel/jetstream#installation
- https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/inertia/laravel-8-jetstream-livewire-inertia-error

Answer (score 0):

this is version issue

try this its working fine

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel:^8.0 example-app

composer require laravel/jetstream:*
```

Answer (score -1):

I try to install fresh laravel (specific laravel project like this):

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel:^8.0 olshop-larafel
```

then inside into this project

```
cd olshop-larafel
```

And install laravel/jetstream:

```
composer require laravel/jetstream
```

All works fine. Have you tried to install laravel 8.0 specific version?

Or maybe this [article will help you](https://github.com/laravel/jetstream/issues/838)

Information, this is my composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.0",
        "laravel/jetstream": "^2.3",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.3.6",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```